# How can I replace all occurrences of 0 with 1 in my dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a dataframe that looks something like

`duration   count
0            23
2            12
0            43
2            12
0            43
4            65
1            22`

I simply want to replace all of the 0's in the duration column with 1. I tried to do this by

`df_sorted = df_sorted.replace(df_sorted['duration'] == 0, df_sorted['duration'] == 1)`

However, I run this and the dataframe seems unaffected. I do not get an error message and nothing seems to change. I am working with a much bigger dataframe with a lot more rows/columns so maybe I'm missing that something else is changing? Regardless, the 0's still remain after I run the line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### short and sweet

```
df_sorted['duration'] += df_sorted['duration'].eq(0)

df_sorted

   duration  count
0         1     23
1         2     12
2         1     43
3         2     12
4         1     43
5         4     65
6         1     22
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly! Can I ask exactly what the `.eq(0)` is doing?

Comment: It’s a method that checks equality. Same as ==

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where` which is somewhat similar to a `case when` from sql.

```
df['duration'] = np.where(df['duration'] == 0,1,df['duration'])
```

Which reads as: Check the value of each row of `df['duration']`, if it's equal to 0, replace it with a 1, otherwise, return `df['duration']`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `inplace=True` which essentially make the change permanent.

*Note: `inplace=True` returns None `inplace=False` returns a copy of the object with the operation performed.*

```
df_sorted = pd.DataFrame({'duration':[1,0,2,0],'Count':[23,23,2,1]})
df_sorted.replace({'duration': {0:1}}, inplace=True)
print(df_sorted)
```